# What is the difference between the kurtosis function in DolphinDB and the kurt function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dolphindb, kurtosis

The `kurt` function seems to support only unbiased estimation while the `kurtosis` function returns a biased result by default. How to make the `kurt` result in pandas consistent with that of `kurtosis(biased=true)` in DolphinDB?

Comment: Please, edit the title so that accurately reflects your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kurtosis` function in DolphinDB returns a biased result by default (biased = true), while in pandas it returns an unbiased result, and the kurtosis value “3” of the normal distribution is subtracted.

In Python, you can use `scipy.stats.kurtosis(x, fisher=False)` to achieve the behavior of `kurtosis(x)` in DolphinDB.